# Two-line editing comment causes incorrect format on suggested edits page

Tags: bug, design

When suggested edit on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits) (requires 10k rep) has quite long editing comment, it takes two lines and the text floating block is displayed below the avatar like "Get started with Latex on Linux" on this screenshot:

[image: incorrect formatting]

I observe this problem in both Firefox and Chrome. Looks like a bug.